# Using Crystal Reports in VB.net windows app

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, pervasive

I've done much googling and tested various code no avail, so before anyone cries "DUPLICATE" please read the question through.

*The Scenario:*  I have a windows form written in **VB.net using visual studio 2013**.  I have installed the Crystal Reports API, and I've opened an existing report which was provided with Sage Business Vision and removed all the fields (basically stripped it down to just the layout).  I need to pull data from 3 different tables in my pervasive database to use in this report.

*What I've accomplished:* So far, I've created a form and named it 'RPTviewer' and I've dropped the Crystal Report Viewer on it (and left the default name 'CrystalReportViewer1'

*The Struggle:*  I'm having difficulty getting the report to display much of anything.  I've tried using the SQL expression fields, but they won't let me use the WHERE clause.  It seems I can only specify PART of a SQL string between the 'SELECT' and 'FROM' clauses.[image]

My work around for this was to just do all the querying in the windows form and inject the information into predefined fields.  I've tried this using an 'Unbound Field':

```
Private Sub RPTviewer_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim rpt As New OfficeCopyPS

    Dim crOrderNumber As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject
    crOrderNumber = rpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects("OrderNumber")
    crOrderNumber.Text = "1234567"


    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
    CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
    rpt.Load()



End Sub
```

however, all that gets me at run time is a blank viewer.  I've also tried using a Parameter Field, but it just prompts me for a value at run time and ignores what I specified in the form_load event (it does load the report though).

```
        rpt.SetParameterValue("OrderNumber", "1234567")
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
    CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
    rpt.Load()
```

[image]

There has to be a way to do this.  Is there any documentation?  Can anyone suggest a better way to get the information I need into the report?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you having issues with displaying fields from the tables using the datascource connected to the report?  For this sorta thing, I usually have used formulas.  As [Expressions are pretty limited](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=1377)

Comment: I've only had a day to play with this so I'm not sure how to use formulas.  But it's good to know that I shouldn't bother with expressions

Comment: Well they have their place, but your report isn't running slow.  I've not used them, but I did think of an instance where this would have sped up a report for me.  I just use the dataset designer, set it to the source of the report and then you can filter the query in code as necessary.

Comment: Right there! That's what I need!  How do I filter the query?  Is that also in the formula fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it.  I'll summarise my findings here:  Parameters are just that:  Parameters.  They can be used to pass information to functions and query data.  Under database expert, you can create a command with a WHERE clause using one or more parameters defined at the time the command is created.

My big problem was trying to pass the parameters before the report was loaded.  below is the correct order:

```
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
rpt.Load()
rpt.SetParameterValue("OrderNumber", "1234567")   'use this to pass parameters
rpt.DataDefinition.FormulaFields("FORMULAFEILDNAME").Text = "'" & This appears in formula & "'"   'This inserts into a formula feild.
    CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
```

Above is a sample of passing to both parameter and a formula feild.  Formula feilds, unlike parameters seem to need to be placed on the report to receive a value.  Like the name suggests, formula fields accept formulae as well as functions, loops, decision structure and variables.  Note in the code above, I had to encapsulate the string in single quotes so the formula would display it.